How do I select a MUI TextField MenuItem in my React unit tests?
I'm using a MUI drop down in my React app:


<Box>
        <TextField
          select
          label="Education Level"
          id="education"
          data-testid="education"
          style={{ width: 400 }}
          {...register("education", {
            required: {
              value: true,
              message: "Education level is required",
            },
          })}
        >
          {EDUCATION_OPTIONS.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
              {option}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
        <p className="error">{errors.education?.message}</p>
      </Box>



I'm trying to unit test the drop down with the following:


    const education = screen.getByTestId("education");

fireEvent.mouseDown(education);
    const eduSelect = screen.getByRole('option', {name: "Associate Degree"})
    fireEvent.click(eduSelect)



I've also tried screen.getByText('Associate Degree').
I've Googled and tried ChatGPT to no avail but it fails on

71 |     const eduSelect = screen.getByRole('option', {name: "Associate Degree"})

Here's the error in the console:
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "option" and name "Associate Degree"

When I inspect the console I get the following:

Any help would be appreciated.
I came close to resolving the issue using


    expect(gender).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.change(gender, {target: {name: 'Female'}});



But when I assert the values it fails with the following:
Expected the element to have value:
  Female
Received:
  undefined

It's weird that didn't work because I didn't get an error on the change event.
Troubleshooting even more I tried changing the component to the following:


          <Box>
            <TextField
              select
              label="*Smoking Frequency"
              id="smokingHabits"
              data-testid="smokingHabits"
              style={{ width: 400 }}
              {...register("smokingHabits", {
                required: {
                  value: true,
                  message: "Required",
                },
                onChange: (e) => setValue("smokingHabits", e.target.value),
              })}
            >
              {FREQUENCY.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                  {option}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
            <p className="error">{errors.smokingHabits?.message}</p>
          </Box>





    expect(element).toHaveValue(Occasionally)

    Expected the element to have value:
      Occasionally
    Received:
      undefined



